# Java 8 result chaining

Tags: java, java-stream, chain

I am very new to Java 8.

I want to do the below operation in Java 8 possibly using streams. Is there a way to do it? 
The main goal is feed output of one to another method using the best possible java 8 way.

```
public Fob getFob(String paramString){
    Optional<Foo> foo = getFoo(paramString);
    if (foo.isPresent()) {
        Optional<Bar> bar = getBar(foo.get().fooParamString);
        if (bar.isPresent()) {
            Optional<Fob> fob = getFor(bar.get().barParamString);
            if (fob.isPresent()) {
                return fob.get();
            } else {
                log.error("fob is not present");
            }
        } else {
            log.error("bar is not present");
        }
    } else {
        log.error("foo is not present");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you need the logging for missing cases, stick with what you have. There's nothing inherently better about a `Stream`; if you have clear code that works, why shoehorn a `Stream` into it?

Comment: As a way to improve this code without streams, I recommend inverting the `if` conditions so that the error messages each appear next to the condition which checks for them.

Answer (score 2):

In a now deleted comment I said to look into [`Optional#map(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) but I now realize you should actually be using [`Optional#flatMap(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)), assuming the logging statements are not too important. This is because your mapping functions will return `Optional` objects but you only care about the potentially wrapped value. Ignoring the logging statements, the following should be equivalent to your current code:

```java
public Fob getFob(String paramString) {
  return getFoo(paramString)                       // Optional<Foo>
      .flatMap(foo -> getBar(foo.fooParamString))  // Optional<Bar>
      .flatMap(bar -> getFor(bar.barParamString))  // Optional<Fob>
      .orElse(null);                               // Fob (may be null)
}
```

Here's the documentation of `#flatMap(Function)`:

> If a value is present, returns the result of applying the given `Optional`-bearing mapping function to the value, otherwise returns an empty `Optional`.
>
> This method is similar to [`map(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), but the mapping function is one whose result is already an `Optional`, and if invoked, `flatMap` does not wrap it within an additional `Optional`.

Basically, in the case where the `Function` returns another `Optional`:

1. When using `map` the **`Optional`** returned by the `Function` is wrapped in the `Optional` returned by the `map` method.

   ```java
   // The function argument is a Function<? super T, ? extends U>
   Optional<Optional<Bar>> opt = getFoo(paramString)
       .map(foo -> getBar(foo.fooParamString));
   ```
2. When using `flatMap` the **value** of the `Optional` returned by the `Function` is wrapped in the `Optional` returned by the `flatMap` method.

   ```java
   // The function argument is a Function<? super T, ? extends Optional<? extends U>>
   Optional<Bar> opt = getFoo(paramString)
       .flatMap(foo -> getBar(foo.fooParamString));
   ```

---

If you want to log which specific value is not present the easiest option is, I think, to move the logging statements to the `getXXX` methods—though that may not be desirable. Otherwise keep using what you're currently using; there's nothing that says you *must* use Java 8 features in new code. I wonder if the logging statements are needed though? If they are, I question why you are logging at the error level. At worst this seems like a warning-level scenario but is more likely to be a debug-level scenario.

Comment: _This method is similar to map(Function), but the mapping function is one whose result is already an Optional, and if invoked, flatMap does not wrap it within an additional Optional._ Could you explain this bit?

Comment: @AshvinSharma Updated answer. Does that help?

Comment: Yep, I understand it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With streams, it is much more difficult because you are now dealing with the `Stream` and `Optional` and you also want to handle the case where the Optionals are empty which also means handling empty streams...it's just a mess so I'd recommend not to do it.

This is one way with `Optionals`. I initially thought it couldn't be done with optionals, but I guess, it can be done with just map.

```
public Fob getFob(String paramString) {
    getFoo(paramString)
    .map(foo -> foo.fooParamString)
    .map(fps -> getBar(fps))
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        // Foo not found
        return Optional.empty();
    })
    .map(bar -> bar.barParamString)
    .map(bps -> getFob(bps))
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        // bar not found
        return Optional.empty();
    })
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        // fob not found
        return null;
    });
}
```

I honestly can't say I'm a fan of it, but it can be done with optionals. There is also the risk of returning `null` when expecting Optional. For example with the last case: if you decide in the future to add a new operation and don't change the `return null` to `return Optional.empty()`, you run the risk of `NullPointerException`.

Comment: If your answer was inspired by [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846861/java-8-result-chaining/58847755#comment103967636_58846861) I believe I was incorrect to suggest `map` and `flatMap` is probably the better choice.

Comment: @Slaw `flatMap` will definitely work, but not if OP wants to chain the calls and still log when the optional is empty

Comment: That's true. Personally, if the logging statements are required and they must be inside the `getFob` method, I wouldn't use `Optional` chaining in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If a similar pattern exists throughout your code, it may be worthwhile to create a helper class modeled after `Optional`.

```
final class Result<T> { /* AKA ElvisImpersonator */

    private final T obj;

    private final String missing;

    private Result(T obj) {
        this.obj = Objects.requireNonNull(obj);
        this.missing = null;
    }

    private Result(String missing) {
        this.obj = null;
        this.missing = Objects.requireNonNull(missing);
    }

    static <T> Result<T> root(T obj) {
        return new Result<>(obj);
    }

    <R> Result<R> next(String name, Function<? super T, Optional<? extends R>> link) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        Objects.requireNonNull(link);
        if (obj == null) return new Result<>(missing);
        Optional<? extends R> opt = link.apply(obj);
        return opt.isPresent() ? new Result<>(opt.get()) : new Result<>(name);
    }

    T orElse(Consumer<? super String> emptyAction, T def) {
        if (this.missing == null) {
            return obj;
        } else {
            emptyAction.accept(this.missing);
            return def;
        }
    }

}
```

Then the convoluted `Optional` based logic could be consolidated like this:

```
public Fob getFob(String paramString) {
    return Result
        .root(paramString)
        .next("foo", this::getFoo)
        .next("bar", foo -> getBar(foo.fooParamString))
        .next("fob", bar -> getFor(bar.barParamString))
        .orElse(n -> log.error(n + " is not present"), null);
}
```

I think the resulting usage is very clean, but clearly not worth all the extra code for just one occurrence.

Comment: Instead of `Optional<? extends R> opt = link.apply(obj); return opt.isPresent() ? new Result<>(opt.get()) : new Result<>(name);` you may use `return link.apply(obj) .map(Result<R>::new).orElseGet(() -> new Result<>(name));`

Comment: @Holger I wrote it this way originally, then saw that, and thought, "of course!" But then when I actually re-wrote it, I felt it looked more complicated than the original, and changed it back. But, it's definitely an option, if another beholder felt differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your requirement can be satisfied using `Stream` or chaining `Optional` in the exact same manner corresponding to your provided code.

Why?
You have nested `if-else` blocks. You can `filter` and then `map` the `if` blocks consecutively to emulate a nested `if` condition but the `else` block will have no other way to get chained. 
So only chaining of `Stream` or `Optional` isn't going to work in your case.

`Stream`s are basically [sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Meaning that you apply transformations on actual elements (often based on conditions) and then you return something after the transformation.
In your case, where this definition breaks is in the nested `else` blocks, because you don't return anything there. If those logging functions returned anything then you could simply chain a bunch of `map`s and get your work done.